# Why does Ubuntu still require restart after kernel updates when tools out there mean it's unnecessary?

Tags: kernel, update-manager, updates, restart

A regular occurrence in updating Ubuntu is kernel updates, which require a restart. There are applications which negate the need for a restart after a kernel update e.g. ksplice.

Why doesn't Ubuntu use tools similar to ksplice? Are there security, memory, etc. concerns to not restarting immediately/ever? Or, can these issues be overcome (i.e. are they just bugs)?

Comment: For now [ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/download-ubuntu) is free to download (but not open-source) for Ubuntu Desktop, shame it's not "free" software (only free in cost).

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, but the accepted answer is here IMO better. It should be migrated if/as this is closed. Thanks!

Comment: htorque's answer here is valuable, so we should merge answers after closing, yes. But in the quoted interview, Peter Graner didn't say anything about *why* ksplice is not included. In contrast, [Kees Cook's answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/10184) does explain *why* (and offers additional technical and practical insight). Kees Cook serves on the [Ubuntu Technical Board](https://launchpad.net/~techboard/+members), so I think that answer, too, should be considered more than mere speculation. Kees Cook's answer is actually why I voted to dupe this to that, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this IRC log from Feb. containing a question and answer session with Peter Graner (pgraner), the Kernel Engineering Manager:

> **<Taek>** QUESTION: Is there plans or even talk about having a system update without having to restart or install third party software such as ksplice.
>
> **<pgraner>**    Taek, the kernel will support kplice however we have no plans to do such a thing, there is already a commercial venture that does that
>
> **<sebsebseb>** QUESTION: Do you think that Ubuntu Desktop might use Ksplice in the future?
>
> **<pgraner>** sebsebseb, No as stated in the last question

Not really a satisfying answer to the *why*, but the best I could find.

Comment: If you view this answer in conjuntion with the answer from Mike. It sounds like they wont use ksplice because there is a commercial venture which holds a patent, which is violated by ksplice

Answer (score 2):

It may be patent encumbered:

http://www.google.com/patents?id=cVyWAAAAEBAJ&dq=hotpatching